# Splitting via regex is duplicating arguments NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm splitting code via regular expressions and it's doing (sort of) the right thing... until the string ends. Would this be a problem with my regex? If so, how would I fix it?

Code:

```js
let args = line.split(/\s(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
console.log("LINE: "+line)
console.log("SPLIT: "+JSON.stringify(args))
```

Output:

```
LINE: var String: test = "Hello"
SPLIT: ["var","String: test = \"Hello\"","Hello\"","String:","test = \"Hello\"","Hello\"","test","= \"Hello\"","Hello\"","=","\"Hello\"","Hello\"","\"Hello\""]
```

Expected Output:

```
LINE: var String: test = "Hello"
SPLIT: ["var", "String:", "test", "=", "\"Hello\""]
```

Comment: The reason why you are getting duplicates is because you have a nested capture group `(([^"]*"){2})`. If you study it carefully you have parenthesis inside parenthesis. So you are asking it to capture the inner contents twice.

Comment: @StephenQuan Thanks, I'll try removing it.

Comment: @StephenQuan That seems to output `[ 'var String: test = "Hello"' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `String.match(regex)` not `String.split(regex)`. I would design a regex that has the following characteristics:

- Capture `=`, or
- Capture quoted string, or
- Capture unquoted alphabet string
- And add an optional ':' suffix

e.g.

```js
let line = `var String: test = "Hello"`;
let m = line.match(/(=|"[^"]*"|\w+):?/g);
console.log(m);
// [ "var", "String:", "test", "=", "\"Hello\"" ]
```